# JS: Sort only one field of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the next array structure:

```
const arr = [
   {
      label: 'Apple',
      data: [{test: '1'}, {test: '2'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '1'}, {test: '2'}],

   },
   {
      label: 'Orange',
      data: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
   },
   {
      label: 'Tomato',
      data: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],

   },
   {
      label: 'Banana',
      data: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
   }
]
```

I also have a method to sort an array - `sortArr` - sorts an array by alphabet.

I need to iterate over `arr` and apply `sortArr` to `data` and `collapsedData` if the label is `Apple`.

So, `data` and `collapsedData` should be sorted for `Apple` label.

Desired output:

```
const outputArr = [
   {
      label: 'Apple',
      data: [{test: '2'}, {test: '1'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '2'}, {test: '1'}],

   },
   {
      label: 'Orange',
      data: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
   },
   {
      label: 'Tomato',
      data: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],

   },
   {
      label: 'Banana',
      data: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
      collapsedData: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
   }
]
```

What can be the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: A loop and an `if`

Comment: @Andreas Could you please share an example?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { if (...) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on below:

```
function sortExceptApples(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      if (arr[i].label !== "Apple")
        arr[i] = { ...arr[i], data: sortArr(arr[i].data), collapsedData: sortArr(arr[i].collapsedData) }
 return arr
}
```

and then:

```
let outputArr = sortExceptApples(arr)
```

Comment: arr is your output, and it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question

> I need to iterate over `arr` and apply sortArr to data and collapsedData if the label is Apple.

1. First filter your `arr` with `arr.filter(x => x.label == 'Apple')` to get only `Apple` record.
2. Then loop over it with `forEach` and sort your inner object `data` & `collapsedData`
3. Keep in mind that `data` is `array` of `object`, so need to filter with its property value like `a.test`. I've attached `+` before `a.test` which will convert value to `number`.

You can check output below.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    label: 'Apple',
    data: [{test: '2'}, {test: '1'}],
    collapsedData: [{test: '2'}, {test: '1'}],

  },
  {
    label: 'Orange',
    data: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
    collapsedData: [{test: '3'}, {test: '4'}],
  },
  {
    label: 'Tomato',
    data: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],
    collapsedData: [{test: '5'}, {test: '6'}],

  },
  {
    label: 'Banana',
    data: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
    collapsedData: [{test: '7'}, {test: '8'}],
  }
];

const t = () => {
    arr.filter(x => x.label == 'Apple')
        .forEach(x => {
          x.data.sort((a,b) => +a.test - +b.test);
          x.collapsedData.sort((a,b) => +a.test - +b.test);
        });
    return arr;
}        
console.log(t());
```

Comment: What does this function return? If I use it like this:
const t = () => {
  return arr.filter(x => x.label == 'Apple')
    .forEach(x => {
      x.data.sort((a,b) => +a.test - +b.test);
      x.collapsedData.sort((a,b) => +a.test - +b.test);
    })
};

it returns undefined

Comment: `forEach` will not return anything, so you are getting `undefined. You need to add `return arr;` to next line. Then it will work you've expected. Also I have updated my answer.

Comment: `filter` will return `array` but `forEach` won't return anything. So you can do like `const filteredArr = arr.filter(...);` and then `filteredArr.forEach(...)`. Then `return filteredArr;`.